# Best strategy for defending last Institute mission

Tags: fallout-4

At the end of the campaign and siding with the Institute...

> I have to defend Liberty Prime from the entire Brotherhood of Steel. I'm playing on the hardest difficulty and even with power armor, I don't seem to be coming up with a good hiding spot or vantage point. It's very easy to get surrounded and flanked by multiple knights, Danse and other power armor users.

I'm playing on Survival difficulty, and my character uses full-auto guns with Commando.

What is the best way to complete the quest?

Comment: This seemed (to me) like on of those missions where you bring buckets of explosives/mini nukes/etc. and sit in a corner lobbing them at everyone you see. Go for fusion cores in power armor. Focus on one piece of the armor and destroy it rather than random pieces/all pieces.

Comment: @DangerZone Yeah planting mine after mine at one of the entrances might work if I spec'd into explosives at all. I don't think I've used a single mine throughout my playthroughs. Just not my style. Maybe I need to change that!

Comment: not all that necessary, although it wouldn't hurt. I hadn't upgraded any explosive-related stats at all. But since you haven't used and, you should probably have a bunch laying around!

Comment: This will depend heavily on your character's build. What kind of character do you have? The difficulty will also be a factor. What difficulty are you playing on? I did this on two different playthroughs on normal with a pistol-wielder, and just stood on top of the platform with the Deliverer and killed everything.

Comment: @DCShannon Hardest, commando (auto guns)

Comment: You mean Survival difficulty? Yeah, killing guys in Power Armor on survival difficulty with full auto guns would be pretty hard. Good luck with that.

Comment: It's not a strategy, but an automatic weapon with the "Wounding" legendary weapon effect will make this quest (and just about everything else in the game) easier. If you hit someone with it, their health will drop for a few seconds after you hit them, so if you get an enemy down to 25% health or so you can often turn your attention to another enemy while the first one bleeds out, making it a bit easier to deal with large mobs like this battle. The bleeding effect stacks per-bullet, so if you score a few hits on full-auto, the effect really adds up.

Comment: @DanC Even better, a shotgun. The effect stacks with each pellet, making it _ridiculously overpowered_. You can kill a Behemoth in about 4 shots on Normal with no other mods on the gun.